# Struts 2 unable to load interceptor file

Tags: java, struts2, struts, interceptor

I'm new to struts2 and I'm having problems loading the custom interceptor file into my demo Struts2 application.  I have tested and checked all my java, jsp and xml files and everything seems ok.  At run time I have the following error and I'm not sure how to fix it.  The application works but the interceptor is not invoked and the print line statements are not printed.

```
WARNING: Unable to load config class com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor at interceptor -     file:/Users/faraichirawu/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/AO/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:16:86 probably due to a missing jar, which might be fine if you never plan to use the LoginInterceptor interceptor
Jan 05, 2014 4:27:20 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder error
SEVERE: Actual exception
Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor - interceptor - file:/Users/faraichirawu/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/AO/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:16:86
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:202)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:70)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:1110)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildInterceptorList(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:626)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:440)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:552)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:292)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:258)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:128)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:181)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:42)
... 26 more
```

this is my struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">  
<struts>

<!-- <constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/WEB-INF/" /> 
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller" /> <constant 
    name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="default" /> <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" 
    value="default" /> <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" 
    value="false" /> -->

<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/admin/accounts">
      <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="LoginInterceptor" class="com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="LoginInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors> 

    <global-results>
        <result name="login">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="login">
        <result>/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="loginAction" class="com.ao.admin.administrator.accounts.LoginAction">
        <result name="success" type="chain">welcomeAction</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="welcomeAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="logoutAction" class="com.ao.admin.administrator.accounts.LogoutAction">
        <result name="success">/WEB-INF/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

The jar lib files have loaded are 
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar 
commons-io-2.2.jar 
commons-lang-2.4.jar 
commons-lang3-3.1.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar 
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar 
freemarker-2.3.19.jar 
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar 
ognl-3.0.6.jar 
struts2-config-browser-plugin-2.3.16.jar 
struts2-core-2.3.16.jar 
xwork-core-2.3.16.jar

this is the custom interceptor class

```
package com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor;


import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class LoginInterceptor implements Interceptor
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

    String className = invocation.getAction().getClass().getName();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Before calling action: " + className);

    String result = invocation.invoke();

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("After calling action: " + className
            + " Time taken: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");

    return result;
}

public void destroy() {
    System.out.println("Destroying MyLoggingInterceptor...");
}
public void init() {
    System.out.println("Initializing MyLoggingInterceptor...");
}
}
```

Comment: Post the interceptor class code include the `package` statement.

Comment: The class `com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor` (which is named incorrectly based on Java naming conventions) is not being deployed, just like the error message says.

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute is incomplete

In your struts.xml replace

```
<interceptor name="LoginInterceptor" class="com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor" />
```

with

```
<interceptor name="LoginInterceptor" class="com.ao.businessobjects.interceptor.LoginInterceptor" />
```

"class" is the full path of your interceptor,
"name" is the logical name that will be used in struts.xml